# Exporting a transparent TChart PNG distorts text

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I'm using Steema TeeChart v4.1.2010.11303. I want to export a chart to a PNG image with a **transparent background**.

The resulting image has **"distorted" or bold text** in the left and bottom axis and in the header. It looks like being rendered with a raster font with a too low resolution. The legend on the right on the other hand looks fine:

[image: TeeChart with distorted text]

The following sample code can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
TChart tChart = new TChart();
tChart.Aspect.View3D = false;
tChart.Panel.Brush.Gradient.Visible = false;

// Make the background of the chart transparent.
tChart.Panel.Transparent = true;

Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar series1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar( tChart.Chart );
series1.FillSampleValues();
tChart.Draw();
tChart.Graphics3D.BufferStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.BufferStyle.None;

using ( System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream() )
{
    tChart.Export.Image.PNG.Width = m_PictureBox.Width;
    tChart.Export.Image.PNG.Height = m_PictureBox.Height;
    tChart.Export.Image.PNG.Save( stream );
    // Show the bitmap in a Windows Forms PictureBox.
    // Alternatively, it can also be saved in a file, which makes no difference.
    PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap( stream );
}
```

When switching off the transparency with `tChart.Panel.Transparent = false;`, all text looks fine. However, I need a transparent background.

Is this a bug in TeeChart or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is a know behavior for us and we haven't found a good solution for this problem, for the moment. If we will find a solution that we consider correct or we will arrive an interesting conclusion about problem of png export, we will inform you immediatly.

Thanks.

Best Regard,
Sandra Pazos